# What are the precautions to be taken while Install Ubuntu 18.04 into a SSD?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I have PC installed Ubuntu 18.04 in its Sata-HDD. As performance is not satisfactory so I bought a 120GB Sata-SSD. I want to make it primary (bootable) Storage and install Ubuntu 18.04 into the SSD. Also want to keep the old HDD  as Secondary storage where old OS was installed. I do not want dual boot, want single Ubuntu runs from SSD only. I never do that before, So, seeking step by step guild line, precautions on this scenario from experts. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General description:

1. Make backups of any data you wish to keep.
2. Disconnect the HDD temporarily.
3. Connect the SSD as primary drive.
   *This will make grub and /boot be on this disk!

   Which might be important if you wish to remove or replace the HDD later.*
4. Install Ubuntu as normal.
5. Google for instructions on how to "move /home" and follow them.
   Note that the best is to make a backup of all the hidden
   files in the newly installed /home - i.e. move these to the new location.
6. Move back all backups.
7. Manually check for differences from saved $HOME/.config files and similar; do not copy/replace anything unless you **know** that won't hurt anything.

*I'd recommend using 20.04, but this means abandoning Python 2. for starters.*

*Personally I'd make the HDD be empty (leave or create just one large partition) as it allows for easiest use.*
*Note that this also makes it fairly easy to migrate from one Ubuntu to next.*

---

**Alternatively**: keep the HDD connected, and define /home to be on the HDD in the disk setup / partitioning in the installation procedure (hmm... is that possible? Can't remember!).

---

The description for "move /home" applies also if you do not wish to have the HDD as /home or even /home/$USER/ (user's home-dir) - just create a folder elsewhere under the root (/) and mount the disk there instead - that is the only difference from the "move /home" -description.

Comment: What if I take a backup of HDD and format it to ext4. Then I connect the hard disk and use like a removable drive. Is it possible?

Comment: Absolutely, just put the disk in e.g. a USB-cabinet. As you connect the USB-cable it will appear just as a normal thumb-drive. Note though that I'd recommend to make sure all parts are USB3 here, firstly due to the speed, but most importantly to have the drive get all the power it might need (depends on the HDD requirements).

Comment: I want to connect HDD using SATA port actually.

Comment: Yes, possible of course, even if you don't wish to have it as /home - make it be named something else and place wherever you wish in the filesystem tree, if you wish so. The description of moving /home gives all details. Just create a folder e.g. under / (root) and mount it there instead, that's the only difference.